# Comparative - dollars became more valuable as toilet paper than currency

Tags: comparatives

> **New Zimbabwe dollars** became more valuable as toilet paper than **currency**.

I saw this sentence in an English exam. Is it a correct sentence? 
It seems to me that new Zimbabwe dollars is compared with currency. Am I wrong?

Comment: It's grammatical, but it's got several parts that show the structure left out. A fuller version would be _NZ$ became more valuable as toilet paper than they are valuable as currency._ This is comparing the relative values of the paper currency for different purposes.

Comment: @John Lawler Thank you so much.

Comment: Or, putting it another way, at one point in the economic collapse of Zimbabwe toilet paper cost more than one dollar a sheet.